# How to build jar files for apertium translation pairs

Tags: jar, compilation, translation, apertium

I am new to apertium. When I tried to generate the jar file for the language pair it gives the following error.

> apertium@ap-vbox:~/lttoolbox/lttoolbox-java$ ./apertium-pack-j
>   /home/apertium/apertium-trunk/apertium-svn/apertium-ca-it1/modes/ca-it.mode
>   cp: cannot stat
>   ''\''/home/apertium/apertium-trunk/apertium-svn/apertium-ca-it1/ca-it.automorf.bin'\''':
>   No such file or directory     zip warning: name not matched:
>   data/ca-it.automorf.bin'

But these files are present in the specified path.

Can you please help me to resolve this error?

Comment: Tino already answered at https://sourceforge.net/p/apertium/discussion/481031/thread/56daa7e8/?limit=25#d464